# how do i add an attribute email string into an ahref tag?

Tags: html, css

i have a attr

```
<img class="img_thumb" src="images/cropped9.jpg" author-email="huizhong@hotmail.com">
```

and a

```
<a class="email" href="mailto:">huizhong@hotmail.com"</a>
```

i want to make a email link that is clickable, i read and understand i just have to do

```
<a href="mailto:huizhong@hotmail.com"></a>
```

but my email is in a img attribute, so i wonder how i can add it into the href?

Thanks

Comment: or use a `background-image` for `a` tag

Comment: exract the value of `author-email` with jquery

Comment: wrap the img tag with the a tag: <a href="...."><img .... /></a>

Comment: wrap the <a href around the image tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) on the `img` element to get the `author-email` attribute and set `a` element's `href` attribute:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/8dteweqx/)

```
var image = document.getElementsByClassName('img_thumb')[0];

var a = document.getElementsByClassName('email')[0];
a.href = "mailto:" + image.getAttribute('author-email');

console.log(a)
```